# How do I produce great quality AAC files under Xenial Xerus?

Tags: 16.04, codecs, convert, encoding, aac

I would like to produce high quality AAC files from a small library of wav files under Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS.

I am keen to be able to select between AAC-LC, HE-AAC and HE-AAC v2 for the output files. I am not all that fussed if either a commandline or gui tool does a better job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Xenial Xerus the best choice is to use fdkaac:

```
sudo apt-get install fdkaac
```

Then the following syntax should be helpful, all examples are for Constant Bitrate Mode (CBR) although I have included a section at the bottom concerning Variable Bitrate Mode (VBR):

**1. AAC-LC**

For a single file try this:

```
fdkaac --bitrate 128k --moov-before-mdat --afterburner 1 -o output.m4a input.wav
```

and for a directory of wav files try the following:

```
mkdir aac && \
for j in *.wav
do 
fdkaac --bitrate 128k --moov-before-mdat --afterburner 1 -o aac/"${j%.wav}.m4a" "$j"
done
```

Tested and working well on my system.

**2. HE-AAC**

For a single file try this:

```
fdkaac -p 5 --bitrate 64k --moov-before-mdat --afterburner 1 -o output.m4a input.wav
```

and for a directory of wav files try the following:

```
mkdir aac && \
for j in *.wav
do 
fdkaac -p 5 --bitrate 64k --moov-before-mdat --afterburner 1 -o aac/"${j%.wav}.m4a" "$j"
done
```

Tested and working well on my system.

**3. AAC-HEv2**

For a single file try this:

```
fdkaac -p 29 --bitrate 32k --moov-before-mdat --afterburner 1 -o output.m4a input.wav
```

and for a directory of wav files try the following:

```
mkdir aac && \
for j in *.wav
do 
fdkaac -p 29 --bitrate 32k --moov-before-mdat --afterburner 1 -o aac/"${j%.wav}.m4a" "$j"
done
```

Tested and working well on my system.

**4. VBR Note:**

If you wish to use Variable Bitrate (VBR) mode instead of Constant Bitrate (CBR) simply omit the `--bitrate` setting and use `--bitrate-mode` instead. `bitrate-mode` takes a setting from 1 to 5 with a higher value producing a higher bitrate.

**Further Reading:**

- [Hydrogen Audio: Fraunhofer FDK AAC](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC)
- [abcde: Encoding with fdkaac](http://www.andrews-corner.org/abcde.html#fdkaac)
- [GitHub: fdkaac](https://github.com/nu774/fdkaac)